# Attempting to find the average of 3 quiz grades from 4 students (defined by user input), and I am not sure what is wrong (code below)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

Essentially, the goal is to take 4 students and enter 3 quiz grades a student. Once you have these grades (out of 10), you take the average grade per student and display it. Though, this code outputs something of a different nature with averages that certainly do not seem correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_STUDENTS 4
#define NUM_QUIZZES 3

int main() {


//beginning of part 2 code
    int arr_grades[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_QUIZZES];
    int st_val, students, quizzes;
//introduce the program
    printf("\n\nHello Professor, and welcome to the grading portal.\n\n");

    for (students = 0; students < NUM_STUDENTS; students++) {
        //this allows the entry of three quiz grades per student to be stored
        printf("Please enter 3 quiz grades for student %d: ", students+1);
        for (quizzes = 0; quizzes < NUM_QUIZZES; quizzes++)
            scanf("%d", &arr_grades[students][quizzes]);
    }
//here we will be getting the average of our inputs
    printf("\nAverage Quiz Grades\n");
    for (students = 0; students < NUM_STUDENTS; students++) {
        printf("Student %d's average is: ", students+1);
        //initialize
        st_val = 0;
        //this is the next look that will mimic the same for quizzes then provide       us with the final result
        for (quizzes = 0; quizzes < NUM_QUIZZES; quizzes++)
            st_val += arr_grades[students][quizzes];
            printf("%3d\n", st_val / NUM_STUDENTS);
}
```

Input:

```
Please enter 3 grades for student 1:  10 10 10
Please enter 3 grades for student 2:  2 0 1
Please enter 3 grades for student 3:  8 6 9
Please enter 3 grades for student 4:  8 4 10
```

Wrong Output:

```
    Average Quiz Grades
Student 1's Average is:   7
Student 2's Average is:   0
Student 3's Average is:   5
Student 4's Average is:   5
```

Expected Output:

```
    Average Quiz Grades
Student 1's Average is:   10.0
Student 2's Average is:   1.0
Student 3's Average is:   7.7
Student 4's Average is:   7.3
```

Comment: Maybe show us the input, output and the expected output?

Comment: what's `students`? Please provide a [mre] and ensure the code posted in your question is the code you're running with.

Comment: `printf("%3d\n", st_val / NUM_STUDENTS);` -> `printf("%3d\n", st_val / NUM_QUIZZES);`

Comment: You also have some misleading indentation in your last `for` loop. Include the `printf` in brackets `{ ... }` or move it left.

Comment: @alex01011 Hello, I am sorry for the vagueness and I have edited the content to include these details.

Comment: @yano Thank you, I will adjust that. I have also included the declarations of ```students``` and ```quizzes``` as they were higher up in my code -- I do apologize.

Comment: @user3386109 Edited; I apologize for the vagueness in my question, I have corrected it with the examples. I appreciate the response.

Comment: @neelish Looks good!!! Thanks for improving the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you calculate the average. Divide by the **number of quizzes** per student ***not*** by the number of **students**.

In addition, `%d` will display the average in a **signed integer** format, therefore you will lose precision (you are dividing two integers, the result will be an integer).
You can use `%lf` to display the result as a `double`.

Change this line:

```
printf("%3d\n", st_val / NUM_STUDENTS);
```

to:

```
printf("%.3lf\n",(double) st_val / NUM_QUIZZES);
```

It's also a good idea to check the return value of `scanf()`, you can't be sure if it succeeded.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, thank you. I would upvote the post but I don't have enough reputation, so I apologize for that.